# Fit div to size of contents without overlapping text?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am a very new (see: about a week) CSS user trying to do something that I think is pretty simple. I'm trying to (in a paragraph of text) post an image that is a help icon, that will display more information when you hover over it.

I'm having a bit of a problem with getting my divs to align correctly. I'd like the div containing the picture to only trigger when you hover over the help icon itself, not the entire line it's on. On my code (although not exactly in jsfiddle), I can do this with positioning it absolutely, however this causes the text below it to be overlapped when you use the hover. If I position it any other way, it doesn't overlap, but it isn't fit to the picture. It's back to only working on the entire line.

Is there a way to both fit a div to its contents (a small ~25x25 help icon) and then cause the hover below to not overlap what's under it? I'm trying to keep it on just css.

http://jsfiddle.net/YbGE6/ <--- Very basic jsfiddle format.

```
<div id = "Big">
<div id = "one"> "Hover" <div id="two"> "Hover text" </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Too bad you didn't bother to post some code.  Someone might have been able to help you.

Comment: I posted a jsfiddle... that's literally all the code that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS for the `div` with the help icon to include `display: inline-block;`, which will cause it to fit its contents. `div` is by default `display: block;` which stretches across the entire line.  Do not position the `div` absolutely, use the default static position, and have it `float` to wherever you want. The text will flow around it, and when the size of the help div changes on hover, it will push the text aside and the text will reflow around it.

Here is some documentation for `float`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float